# JS/jQuery/PHP: trying to generate an URL using PHP variables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i'm generating this code

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/orders/modify/action/',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'id='+10+
              '&commento='+$('#shop_order_status_history_comments').val()+
              '&id_status='+$('#shop_order_status_history_orders_status_id').val()+
              '&notify_client='+$('#shop_order_status_history_notify_client').val()+
              '&local_part_email='+j.garpe+   // the error goes here
              '&domain_email='+domain.com,
        success:function(data){
```

But I'm getting this error:

> "Uncaught referenceError: j is not
>   defined".

The code is this:

```
      ...  
      '&local_part_email='+<?php echo $local_part_email?>+
      ...
```

Any help?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be in quotes, like this:

```
'&local_part_email=<?php echo $local_part_email?>'+
```

...but you'll have the same problem with `domain` next, it's best to put it in quotes *and* let jQuery create the string, by passing an object to `data` like this:

```
data: {id: 10,
       commento: $('#shop_order_status_history_comments').val(),
       id_status: $('#shop_order_status_history_orders_status_id').val(),
       notify_client: $('#shop_order_status_history_notify_client').val(),
       local_part_email: '<?php echo $local_part_email?>',
       domain_email: '<?php echo $whatever_domain_variable_here?>' }
```